# Which piece of the mac OS and Linux handle the keyboard and mouse input and how can I capture it?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I am programming a little game and I want to be able to capture keyboard and mouse events.

I want to code it by myself and I wanted to now which part of the macOs and Linux handle it.

Is it the same part since macOs and Linux kernel are partially based on Unix ?

Comment: It's a broad topic (see [this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11)), which can only be properly answered by referring to a tutorial (making it off-topic here).

Comment: Are you asking: "how do I read raw keyboard, before it is converted to ASCII (text)?

Comment: @ThomasDickey, more a detailed description of TTY handling in Linux...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about low-level differences in MAC-OS vs Gnu/Linux.

However:

- For all systems using X11 (just about all Unixes except MacOs), there are various X11 libraries.
- For a wide range of systems (including Gnu/Linux and Microsoft's Windows, MacOs, android, iOS), there is SDL. A cross-platform platform for graphics, keyboard, mouse. It is often used to create games.
- Unixes: There are libraries, such as curses, that provide lower level control of terminals. I can't remember, but would think it will allow raw keyboard monitoring.

There are other libraries, but I don't remember them.